# Receiving error: No keyword with name '${json_data}= | Evaluate | json.load(open(${json_file})) | json' found

Tags: json, robotframework

Relatively new to robot framework. Using robot 4.0.3 on Windows 10 laptop with Chrome. Loading the Selenium and JSON libraries at the top of the resource file.

Using a JSON file with following contents:

```
{
     "first_name": "test",
     "last_name": "user1",
     "email": "test.user1@homelendingpal.com",
     "company": "test company",
     "phone": "919-123-4567",
     "message": "test user 1 test message"
    }
```

and then trying to load and extract values from it with the following code snippet from the resource robot file:

```
Click Submit Button
       ${json_data}= | Evaluate | json.load(open(${json_file})) | json
       ${name_first}= ${json_data["first_name"]}
       Input Text   //input[@id=input_1_1_3]   $name_first
       ${name_last}= ${json_data["last_name"]}
       Input Text   //input[@id=input_1_1_6]   $name_last
       ${email}= ${json_data["email"]}
       Input Text   //input[@id=input_1_2]   $email
       ${company}= ${json_data["company"]}
       Input Text   //input[@id=input_1_6]
       ${phone}= ${json_data["phone"]}
       Input Text   //input[@id=input_1_3]
       Click Element   xpath=//select[@id=input_1_4]/option[@value=Bank]
       ${message}= ${json_data["message"]}
       Click Element   id=gform_submit_button_1
```

I have tried multiple formats of loading the file and accessing the elements inside of it from various examples returned by Google search of robotframework json. Robot always fails on the evaluate/load statement with the error message in the title.

Comment: You may have to specify json as module. `${json_data}= | Evaluate | json.load(open(${json_file})) | modules=json`

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are preferring the pipe separated formatting but lack the leading pipe. According to the [Robot Framework User Guide](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#pipe-separated-format) You always need the leading pipe character for that to work.

Alternatively, if you are not using the pipes, you will need at least 2 spaces between each element on the line.

For example

```
| Click Submit Button
|  | ${json_data}= | Evaluate | json.load(open(${json_file})) | json
```

and

```
Click Submit Button
    ${json_data}=  Evaluate  json.load(open(${json_file}))  json
```

Would be correct.

Comment: Thanks Morkkis. I changed the resource file to match the second format you listed and now it works. I once again broke the cardinal rule of documentation - reading it completely before diving in and/or asking a question to a public forum.